# How to identify which type of custom authentication is being performed?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

We already multiple authentication flows namely.

1) USER_PASSWORD_AUTH

2) CUSTOM_AUTH

I have recently added another custom_auth

is there a way to check which custom_auth is being performed.

what is best way to handle this.

new custom_auth will only authenticate office addins.

this new custom_auth is single sign on for office addin basically password less flow so existing flows can not be used for this flow.

I am using aws-amplify in office addin

Can I sent arbitrary data in auth.config

so that I know where this custom authentication is triggered from in aws cognito triggers

Comment: comment for down vote is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this custom authentication is only triggered from specific client i.e. office addins

Adding simple client id check will allow to separate custom_authentication flow for each client.

```
if(event.callerContext.clientId === '') {

}
```